# ScrollMagic Fade Scene

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gsap, scrollmagic

That block of my html fade in when the trigger element is activated, but is also fade out when user scroll back past the trigger. I dont want to fade out. I want to fade in and leave it there till user hits f5 or reload the page.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){

 // Init ScrollMagic
 var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

 // build a scene
 var ourScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement: '#project01'
 })
 .setClassToggle('#project01', 'fade-in') // add class to project01
 .addIndicators({
  name: 'fade scene',
  colorTrigger: 'black',
  indent: 200,
  colorStart: '#75C695'
 }) // this requires a plugin
 .addTo(controller);});
```

```css
    .project {
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;}
    .project.fade-in {
    opacity: 1;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>


<div class="container porque" id="porque">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="project01" class="project">
      <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
        <h1>¿Por qué solicitar un servicio Clens?</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 porquearriba">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-money fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <h3>Precio óptimo</h3>
          <p>Estamos muy seguros de que nuestros precios por el servicio de limpieza y calidad serán aceptados por usted.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-comments fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <h3>Feedback activo</h3>
          <p>Lo más importante para nosotros es la confianza de nuestros clientes.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-handshake-o fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <h3>Personal amigable</h3>
          <p>Trabajamos sólo con profesionales. Los proveedores de servicio siempre serán competentes, ordenados y corteses.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 porqueabajo">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <h3>Conveniencia</h3>
          <p>Procederemos a limpiar tu hogar en la fecha y hora solicitada con máxima eficiencia</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <h3>Limpieza y orden</h3>
          <p>Los proveedores de servicio siempre harán el mejor esfuerzo para satisfacer tus altos requerimientos y deseos en el mejor tiempo posible</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <h3>Satisfacción</h3>
          <p>El 90% de nuestros clientes valora nuestros servicios con 5 estrellas</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Check if the code you provided needs fixing to execute properly

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit hard to understand, but maybe this is what you are looking for:

You didn't use a `triggerHook` in your scene. By default the triggerHook is in the vertical middle - inmy snippet I set it to be at the top (value between 0 and 1, ranges from top to bottom of the window).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Init ScrollMagic
  var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

  // build a scene
  var ourScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: '#project01',
      triggerHook: 0
    })
    .setClassToggle('#project01', 'fade-in') // add class to project01
    .addIndicators({
      name: 'fade scene',
      colorTrigger: 'black',
      indent: 200,
      colorStart: '#75C695'
    }) // this requires a plugin
    .addTo(controller);
});
```

```css
.project {
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.project.fade-in {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>


<div class="container porque" id="porque">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="project01" class="project">
      <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
        <h1>¿Por qué solicitar un servicio Clens?</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 porquearriba">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-money fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <h3>Precio óptimo</h3>
          <p>Estamos muy seguros de que nuestros precios por el servicio de limpieza y calidad serán aceptados por usted.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-comments fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <h3>Feedback activo</h3>
          <p>Lo más importante para nosotros es la confianza de nuestros clientes.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-handshake-o fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <h3>Personal amigable</h3>
          <p>Trabajamos sólo con profesionales. Los proveedores de servicio siempre serán competentes, ordenados y corteses.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 porqueabajo">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <h3>Conveniencia</h3>
          <p>Procederemos a limpiar tu hogar en la fecha y hora solicitada con máxima eficiencia</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <h3>Limpieza y orden</h3>
          <p>Los proveedores de servicio siempre harán el mejor esfuerzo para satisfacer tus altos requerimientos y deseos en el mejor tiempo posible</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <h3>Satisfacción</h3>
          <p>El 90% de nuestros clientes valora nuestros servicios con 5 estrellas</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```